# oracle table of records declared in package can't use index by?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Thanks for your kindness
I Declare a record type and table of records in spec of package, I need to use this table type as a return of in pipeline function.
If I add INDEX BY (something) to a table declaration, an error compilation in a pipeline function caused. Why can't use INDEX BY?

Comment: Post the code and explain what you want to do.

Comment: And post the error, too.

Answer (score 10):

It's [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/pcmus.htm#sthref18475) that you cannot use index-by (associative arrays) in pipelined functions. you have to use a nested table (either a pl/sql array defined without "index by" or an SQL type).

```
SQL> create or replace package testpkg
  2  as
  3    type test_rec is record(id number, id2 number);
  4    type test_tab is table of test_rec index by binary_integer;
  5
  6    function test return test_tab pipelined;
  7
  8  end;
  9  /

Warning: Package created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE TESTPKG:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/12     PLS-00630: pipelined functions must have a supported collection
         return type

SQL> create or replace package testpkg
  2  as
  3    type test_rec is record(id number, id2 number);
  4    type test_tab is table of test_rec;
  5
  6    function test return test_tab pipelined;
  7
  8  end;
  9  /

Package created.

SQL>
```